# Class derived from string used as data section

Tags: c++, inheritance

I've got an assignment where I have to "Create a class called Number that is derived from string.  You will use this as a base class to derive your Integer and Double classes." It goes on to say that the data section from the Integer and Double classes will "go away".

"Because Number is derived from string and Integer and Double are derived from Number they all become strings. This gives you a built in data section." What I don't understand is where my data section is now. How do I call it and change it.

"At this point your Number class will only contain the following code:

-A no argument constructor that sets the data section to "0"

-An overloaded constructor that takes a string and sets the data section to the value being passed to it."

```
//Number class with the two constructors
#ifndef NUMBER
#define NUMBER

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Number: public string
{
public:
    Number() : string("0") { }
    Number(string s) : string(s) { }
};
#endif
```

Double class

```
//Double class 
#ifndef DOUBLE
#define DOUBLE
#include <string>
#include "Integer.h"
#include "Number.h"
using std::string;
class Double: public Number
{
private:
    // do i call Number here? like Number data; or double data;?
    // or is the data not here?
    void isNan(string s);
    bool nan = false;
    void recursiveNaN(string::iterator p, string::iterator n);

public:
    // Constructors
    Double();
    Double(double d);
    Double(const Double &d);
    Double(const Integer &i);

    // Functionality
    void equals(double d);
    Double &equals(const Double &d);
    Double add(const Double &d);
    Double sub(const Double &d);
    Double mul(const Double &d);
    Double div(const Double &d);
    double toDouble() const;

    //Primitives
    Double add(double d);
    Double sub(double d);
    Double mul(double d);
    Double div(double d);

    // Operator Overload
    Double operator + (const Double &d);
    Double operator - (const Double &d);
    Double operator * (const Double &d);
    Double operator / (const Double &d);
    Double &operator = (const Double &d);
    bool operator == (const Double &d);
    bool operator == (double d);
    bool operator != (const Double &d);
    bool operator != (double d);

    //String stuff
    Double(string s);
    bool isNan();
    void equals(string s);
    Double &operator = (string s);
    string toString();
};



#endif // !DOUBLE
```

One of our hints was on the void quals(double d) function. The hint was to convert the d to a string then call the equals with overloaded string argument to assign this->.

```
void Double::equals(double d)
{
    stringstream ss;
    ss << d;
    this->equals(ss);
}
void Double::equals(string s)
{
    this->isNan(s);
    if (!this->isNan())
        this->assign(s);
    else
        this->assign("0.0");
}
```

In my mind this would be what he meant but this gives me and error that there's no member function that calls to equals.I just need to know how to call this new data and how to change it. My Number class can't have anymore functions in it either.

Comment: You should note that in general c++ standard library classes aren't well suited for inheriting them, e.g. with `std::string` there aren't any `virtual` functions you can `override`, so inheriting is somewhat pointless. It's probably better just to use an internal `std::string` member variable.

Comment: Who would even derive a number class from a string class to begin with??!

Comment: Yea I don't know how practical deriving from string is but it's required for the assignment.

Comment: Any and all help appreciated

Comment: "*this gives me and error that there's no member function that calls to equals*". Why wouldn't you show us the actual error that you're getting? This could be any of a number of things.

Answer (score 0):

> What I don't understand is where my data section is now. How do I call it and change it.

You don't. A number is a string, since you derived from string. What additional data would you want? You call it by calling any member function of `std::string` or passing an instance of your class to any function that takes a `std::string` (or a reference to one).